# How do I define a component as an attribute of composite component?

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I'm creating a keyboard (composite component) with some specific symbols that the user will be able to insert in text fields. I need to define two components as the keyboard's attributes, p:inputText and p:inputTextarea, to set to these inputs' values the symbol selected by the user.The problem is that I can't use a component as the keyboard attribute, it is not working. In my index.xhtml file, how do I pass the inputText?
Index:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pe="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/pe"
    template="/pages/template/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">


        <p:inputText widgetVar="asd" id="asd" value="#{disciplineController.discipline.description}"/>
        <pe:keyboard textField="asd"/>

<!-- How do I pass the p:inputText as attribute? 
Already tried <pe:keyboard textField="#{asd}"/>, it gets null
-->


    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Keyboard

```
<composite:interface componentType="keyboardComponentBean">
    <composite:attribute name="textField" type="org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputText"></composite:attribute>
    <composite:attribute name="textFieldArea" type="org.primefaces.component.inputtextarea.InputTextarea"></composite:attribute>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:form>
            <ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.SYMBOL_ARRAY}" var="symbol">
            <ui:fragment rendered="#{symbol == cc.attrs.SYMBOL_ARRAY[0]}"> Conjuntos <br /></ui:fragment>
            <ui:fragment rendered="#{symbol == cc.attrs.SYMBOL_ARRAY[11]}"> <br />Símbolos <br /></ui:fragment>
            <ui:fragment rendered="#{symbol == cc.attrs.SYMBOL_ARRAY[24]}"> <br />Subscrito <br /></ui:fragment>
            <ui:fragment rendered="#{symbol == cc.attrs.SYMBOL_ARRAY[39]}"> <br />Sobrescrito <br /></ui:fragment>
            <ui:fragment rendered="#{symbol == cc.attrs.SYMBOL_ARRAY[55]}"> <br />Grego (maiúsculo) <br /></ui:fragment>
            <ui:fragment rendered="#{symbol == cc.attrs.SYMBOL_ARRAY[65]}"> <br />Grego (minúsculo) <br /></ui:fragment>
            <ui:fragment rendered="#{symbol == cc.attrs.SYMBOL_ARRAY[81]}"> <br />Setas <br /></ui:fragment>
            <p:commandButton value="#{symbol}" action="#{cc.addText(symbol)}" />
            </ui:repeat>
    </h:form>
</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

FacesComponent:

```
package br.com.portal.education.Timer;

import javax.faces.component.FacesComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer;

import org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputText;
import org.primefaces.component.inputtextarea.InputTextarea;

@FacesComponent("keyboardComponentBean")
public class Keyboard extends UINamingContainer {

    private final String[] SYMBOL_ARRAY = {..símbolos..};

    public String[] getSYMBOL_ARRAY() {
        return SYMBOL_ARRAY;
    }

    public void addText(String symbol) {
        Object textField = getAttributes().get("textField");
        Object textFieldArea = getAttributes().get("textFieldArea");
            if (textField != null){
                ((InputText) textField).setValue(((InputText) textField).getValue() + symbol);
            }

            if (textFieldArea != null){
            ((InputTextarea) textFieldArea).setValue(((InputTextarea) textFieldArea).getValue() + symbol);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind your input component to an EL expression:

```
<p:inputText widgetVar="asd" id="asd" binding="#{bindedAsd}" value="#{disciplineController.discipline.description}"/>
```

This way you can use it as an attribute:

```
<pe:keyboard textField="#{bindedAsd}" />
```

Comment: It works, thanks! But the getValue() method in the textField variable always returns null, even if I type something. Do you know what could it be?

Comment: as you don't process it to the server, it never get's value.
Add this code to your command button: 
`update=":#{textField.clientId}"`

Comment: Using `:`, i get the error message `Cannot find component with expression ":" referenced from "j_idt94:j_idt95:j_idt96:0:j_idt111".`. Works when removed: `update="#{textField.clientId}"`, but still I can't set the textField value. I'm guessing I'm using the wrong method to get/set it, because it is always null when debugging... May you enlighten me?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write process="..." instead of update="..."

Comment: No problem :) But now, with `process=":#{textField.clientId}"` I'm getting this `javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot find component with expression ":" referenced from "j_idt94:j_idt95:j_idt96:0:j_idt111".`. Removing `:`, it does render the page but it does not work...

Comment: Which PF version and JSF version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Primefaces 4.0